# How is User Experience Different from Service Quality?

Tags: user-expectation, quality-assurance

there.

I'd be interesting to know your opinion between this two concepts.

**User Experience**, as defined by Don Norman:

"User experience" encompasses all aspects of the end-user's interaction with the company, its services, and its products.

And **Service Quality**, from Wikipedia:  in its contemporary conceptualisation, is a comparison of perceived expectations of a service with perceived performance.

It's important to me to clearly outline the difference between this to terms because I have to explain the UX concept to a group of industrial engineering students. I usually get questions on how UX is difference and/or better than regular service quality approaches such as SERVQUAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are extremely different. For starters, **Quality Service** refers to services, while UX refers to services, products, systems, living experiences and so on.

But more important than that: **User Experience is a vast environment with tons of disciplines**, including psychology, computer science, design, architecture, statistics and so on. It also includes CX (customer Experience)

On the other hand, **Service Quality** is just a process belonging to CX. As a matter of fact, it can be reduced to an equation (from the same [Wikipedia definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_quality) you mention):

> SQ=P-E

(Where `SQ = Service Quality`, `P=Perceived Performance` and `E= Perceived Expectations`

Of course, UX can't be reduced to a single equation, because it's a complex net of interlinked disciplines.

As an example: you can measure Service Quality using the [**SERVQUAL**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SERVQUAL) method, as you correctly mention. Now, think about this: **which of the many steps, processes, instances, paradigms and business scenarios are you going to measure in UX?** Just to mention a few: *user research, prototype, CX, usability, accessibility, marketing, statistical analysis, information architecture....* as you can see, it's absolutely impossible to measure all of it. You can measure PARTS of the UX process (for example, **customer satisfaction** would be quite similar to **Quality Service** and as a matter of fact, it's very common to use SERVQUAL as methodology), but you can't *measure UX* as a whole